# Optimize with Rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a block of code like

```
if (this.organization) {
  this.orgService.updateOrganization(this.createOrganizationForm.value).subscribe(() => {
    this.alertify.success(`Organization ${this.organization.name} was updated`);
    this.dialogRef.close(true);
  });
} else {
  this.isLoading$.next(true);
  this.orgService.createOrganization(this.createOrganizationForm.value).subscribe(
    () => {
      this.alertify.success('New organizations was successfully added');
      this.dialogRef.close(true);
      this.isLoading$.next(false);
    },
    (error) => {
      this.alertify.error('\n' + error);
      this.isLoading$.next(false);
    },
  );
}
```

My question is what is the best operator or way to use subscribe only once. Which operator if it exists I can use in Rxjs to optimize it and subscribe it once or if there is some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that the things inside the subscription callbacks could be considered side-effects, I'd say you could use `iif` function to decide the observable along with `tap` and `catchError` operators for the side effects.

Try the following

```js
import { of, iif } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const updateOrg$ = this.orgService.updateOrganization(this.createOrganizationForm.value).pipe(
  tap(() => {
    this.alertify.success(`Organization ${this.organization.name} was updated`);
    this.dialogRef.close(true);
  })
);

const createOrg$ = of(null).pipe(
  tap(() => this.isLoading$.next(true)),
  switchMap(() => this.orgService.createOrganization(this.createOrganizationForm.value)),
  tap(
    () => {
      this.alertify.success('New organizations was successfully added');
      this.dialogRef.close(true);
      this.isLoading$.next(false);
    },
    (error) => {
      this.alertify.error('\n' + error);
      this.isLoading$.next(false);
    }
  )
);

iif(
  () => this.organization,
  updateOrg$,
  createOrg$
).subscribe();
```